# Unsorted references apa-like

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I am required to use the apalike bibliography style for a report. I would like my references unsorted so that they appear in the bibliography in the order that they appear in the document.

Is this possible?

Comment: Surely if you're required to use the `apalike` bibliography style you should not do this. Unsorted references are usually introduced by numbers otherwise they become impossible to find. But `apalike` will not do that for you because it is not designed that way.

Comment: @AlanMunn - If I could upvote your comment more than once, I surely would! As you observe, if authoryear-style citation call-outs are to be generated (and `apalike` can only generate authoryear-style call-outs), it makes no sense whatsoever *not* to sort the bibliographic entries alphabetically by the authors' surnames.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid that was the case. I had hoped that I could keep the same citation format in the bibliography and only change the ordering so that the numbers are assigned in order of appearance. I am quite unaware of how the styles operate. Thanks for letting me know!